# Will a Slave device need a different application than the Master?

Tags: android, bluetooth

All Bluetooth projects I have previously done, had an Android device acting as the `Master`, with a Bluetooth dongle or chip acting as a single `Slave`. The project I am working on will have an Android Tablet acting as the `Master`, then have several other Android Devices acting as the `Slaves`.

What is the best practice in this situation? Should I write two separate applications? One for the master, another for the slaves? Or would it be plausible to use one application for both rolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to just make one application and then just have different code logic based on if the device is a master or a slave.

Instead of doing just a simple SPP connection, you could create a sort of bluetooth "Server" and wait until x number of devices connect to the server and then do whatever it is you want to do in your app.

An example (From the developer guide: [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html))

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                //in your case you wouldn't want to close the server socket since you want to 
                //connect more than one device. So keep listening until you get all the devices. 
                //you're also going to have to use different UUID's for each new device. 
                // mmServerSocket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

In this code the server is closed as soon as one connection is made, in your case you would just keep listening for more sockets until you get all the sockets. You're going to need multiple threads to handle all the connections and some synchronization for handling all the data from all the connections depending on what you intend on doing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm not sure I'm entirely understanding what you said. Would it be possible to implement this without having a set number of devices? I am planning on having a Tablet acting as the master which is running all the time. Then any devices in the area can connect to the Master whenever they want, as long as the piconet isn't full. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: So it isn't a set number of devices?

Comment: If that's the case you would never close the serverSocket until the app closes. The serverSocket Thread would always be running. But you're still going to have to create different threads for every new socket.

Comment: No it is a variable number of devices, thank for your response though. Keeping the serverSocket Thread always running seems to be the solution. Thanks!